# ВЕган или вегАн?

Tags: орфоэпия

Давно волнует этот вопрос. Слово относительно новое, поэтому в словарях его не найти. Многие  ставят ударение на первый слог по аналогии с английским vegan, но как мы знаем, если так говорит большинство, еще не значит, что это правильно. Вопрос: как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Так как словарной фиксации у слова нет, то на данный момент единая норма 
тоже отсутсвует. На практике чаще приходилось слышать ударение на "а", 
что имеет под собой сразу два обоснования. Во-первых "веган" имеет в 
своей этимологической структуре ударную "а" из слова "ВЕГетариАНец", а 
во-вторых слова подобной формы в русском языке как правило имееют 
ударение на второй слог *баран, карман, коран и пр.*

Более подробно доводы за то или иное ударение можно посмотреть в 
обсуждении статьи Википедии "Веганство"

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обсуждение:Веганство#.D0.A3.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5

Comment: Получается, что все будут говорить вЕган, а мы вегАн, то есть в(и)гАн?

Comment: @София, все не все (по поводу французов крепко сомневаюсь), но другие языки нам не указ. Например мы говорим википЕдия, хотя в английском википедИя.

Answer (score 0):

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Уотсон,_Дональд

Дональд Уотсон, англ. Donald Watson (2 сентября 1910 — 16 ноября 2005) — британский общественный деятель, основатель «Веганского общества» и соавтор термина веган. В 1944 году вместе с друзьями основал «Веганское общество» (англ. The Vegan Society) и в течение двух лет сам вёл все дела. Вместе с женой Дороти ввёл в употребление термин веган, образовав его из первых трёх и последних двух букв английского слова vegetarian (вегетарианец или вегетарианский). Таким образом, новый термин означает «начало и конец вегетарианства».

http://go-veg.ru/news/kakaja_raznica_mezhdu_vegetarianstvom_i_veganstvom/2010-05-20-48

Единственной распознавательной чертой веганов является практическое воплощение в жизнь общих для веганства нравственных ценностей, подразумевающих сострадательное отношение к животным и вообще к жизни. Такой образ жизни называется "веганством" (ударение на "е").